# Google Analytics event — click a div

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've just added to my analytics code this simple line:

```
setTimeout("ga('send','event','Adjusted bounce rate','page visit 20 seconds or more')",20000);
```

so I will monitor all the users that will stay on my page for more than 20 seconds.

Now I want to add an event that can let me know if a user has clicked a div.

How can I do that?

SOLVED

```
<div id=MYDIV onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Click on the menu icon', 'Click');">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little fix:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  ga('send','event','Adjusted bounce rate','page visit 20 seconds or more');
},20000);
```

With JQuery:

```
$('#my-div').click(function(){
  ga('send','event','Click','My Div');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="my-div">Click here</div>
```

Comment: I add three more divs to be tracked, is there a way to combine the three js in one?

$('#about_us').click(function(){ga('send', 'event', 'Click on the menu icon', 'ABOUT_US');});
$('#mce-EMAIL').click(function(){ga('send', 'event', 'Click on the e-mail newsletter', 'MCE-EMAIL');});
$('#slid').click(function(){ga('send', 'event', 'Click on the info icon', 'INFO');});

Comment: You could use a [jquery multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) like $('#about_us, #mce-EMAIL, #slid').click.... but you will track the same event ga('send', 'event', 'Click on the div', 'about_us or mce or slid');